# SQL WHERE condition with OR and NULL-values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm making a stored procedure where all the parameters will be used in the WHERE condition.

I know how to handle null-values when i have a query like:

```
WHERE value1 = val1 AND value2 = val2 AND value3 = val3
```

Handle nulls:

```
WHERE (value1 is null OR value1 = val1) 
AND (value2 is null OR value2 = val2) 
AND (value3 is null OR value3 = val3)
```

But how should i for for a query with OR?

```
WHERE value1 = val1 OR value2 = val2 OR value3 = val3
```

Obviously this is not working as i will get all rows

```
WHERE (value1 is null OR value1 = val1) 
OR (value2 is null OR value2 = val2) 
OR (value3 is null OR value3 = val3)
```

How should i solve this?

Comment: You mean that when the value is null then this parameter should be ignored?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: If val2 is null i want to ignore the whole logic OR value2 = val2

Comment: @LordVermillion If `value2` is null, then the other half of that `OR` will by default be ignored.  What are you asking here?

Comment: I think you are plain confused and over complicating things.

Comment: if value2 is null "OR (value2 is null or value2 = val2) will be true for every row in the table.

Comment: Rename the columns to column1 etc, and parameters to param1 etc.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in logic of where. When you want change `AND` to `OR` it means that if only one of the column's value be null the whole where will be true  for all results.

Comment: Showing us sample input and output would go a long way towards letting us help you.

Comment: You will not get all rows. Row with Value1, Value2, Value3 different from val1, val2, val3 but not null will not be returned. I see no problem with the query.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `value1` ... `value3` are supposed to represent the parameters and you are trying to write a procedure with optional parameters...

You would want

```
WHERE   (@value1 is null OR @value1 = val1) 
    AND (@value2 is null OR @value2 = val2) 
    AND (@value3 is null OR @value3 = val3)
```

You should consider adding

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

As these kinds of "catch all" queries are notorious for sub optimal execution plans without.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and here is [a demo](http://rextester.com/CDJG48705) I was working on when you posted this!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ISNULL function, it will return the second value, if the first one is NULL. For example:

```
WHERE ISNULL(value1,*some_value*) = val1 
OR ISNULL(value2,*some_value*) = val2 
OR ISNULL(value3,*some_value*) = val3
```

Comment: This doesn't change the logic which the OP already has, though it might be a more concise way of writing it.

Comment: What should *some_value* be? If i set it to '' the query will return all rows, for example if value2 is null i would like to ignore the whole row OR ISNULL(value2,*some_value*) = val2

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, why not? to me it looks correct way

Comment: @Rahul can you please suggest what *some_value* should be, because if i  set it to OR ISNULL(value2, '') = val2 the query return all rows.

Comment: @LordVermillion The value of some_value depends on wherever you want to receive the row if the value2 is null or not. If yes, it should be just val2, if not, it should be some_value that is definitely not in val2 columns, i.e. '-' or something like that.